# Getting the root parent using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_area">
    <div id="favuorites_header_wrapper" class="header_item">
        <div id="favuorites_header_font" class="noSelect">Open Menue</div>
        <div id="favuorites_header_icon" class="noSelect"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, favuorites_header_wrapper is the children of header_area. And
favuorites_header_font, favuorites_header_icon are childrens of favuorites_header_wrapper.

Now, using jQuery, i want to alert the root parent (i.e header_area) whether you are clicked on children or grand children of the header_area. Thanks for your effort.

**EDIT:** I want to get the ID of the container div(i.e header_area) whenever you clicked on the elements inside it.

I'm using

```
alert((e.target || e.srcElement).parentNode.id);
```

But it is returning the respective parent not the Container Div ID.

Comment: What do you mean by "root parent" and how would you expect to identify it? The root element for the entire page is the `<body>`, so that's the further up the DOM structure you could go. If you want to stop further down you need some way of identifying when that should be.

Comment: I think you can handle this problem by event bubling or event propagation. Do some googling on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'alert the header_area', but you can select it using `closest()`:

```
$('#header_area div').click(function() {
    var $header_area = $(this).closest('#header_area');
    // do something eg. alert the id...
    alert($header_area.prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: I meant that, suppose if you have clicked on the "favuorites_header_icon" div, it should display the id of the root parent in alert. That is 'header_area' in this case.

Comment: @Billy You keep using the phrase "root parent" but *that doesn't mean anything*. You need to define the exact properties that this arbitrary "root parent" has in terms of your page, otherwise the question is unanswerable. Also saying "in this case" suggests there are other, different cases that don't look quite like this one.

Comment: @Billy alerting the `id` seems completely redundant as you already know that to select the element, but I amended my example for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('#header_area div').click(function() {
    var parent_header_area = $(this).closest('#header_area');
});
```

or use [**.parents()**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('#header_area div').click(function() {
    var parent_header_area = $(this).parents('#header_area');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#header_area").find();
```

This wil return all children and subchildren.
You can then add a click-handler to the found elements.
Explanation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.header_area div').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents('.header_area'));
});
```

Comment: That will output "[Object object]" in most browsers.

Comment: He said he wanted to "alert the root parent". This delivers.

Comment: From the code he's tried in the question we can assume he wants the ID of the selected element, so this doesn't "deliver" by any means. The question is crap and needs some substantial edits to provide clarification, either way.

Comment: @Anthony. I want to get the ID of the container div(i.e header_area) whenever you clicked on the elements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$('[id^="favuorites_header"]').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   var parent = $(this).closest('[id^="header_"]').attr('id');
   alert(parent);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R647C/)